# Select item using drop down in selenium using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have just started using selenium in python which is very new to me, I am using it to automate a process. I want to find out how i can use the drop down function to select an item using it's index position.

Please see below image:
[image: Finacle Database Access]

After logging in using selenium functions I would then like to navigate to 'SOLUTION' and select 'F-FINACLE CORE'

Below is the code I have used to login into finacle using selenium in python:

```
##Accessing Finacle
driver = webdriver. Ie(executable_path=r"path")
fin = driver.get("link")
time.sleep(4)
driver.switch_to.frame("loginFrame")
list_id = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')


for i in list_id:
  print(i.text)
login = driver.find_element_by_id("usertxt")


login.send_keys("username") #enter your username 
password = driver.find_element_by_id("passtxt")
password.send_keys('password') #enter you password
password = driver.find_element_by_id("Submit").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Are there really no answers to this either on Stack Overflow or other websites?

Comment: I haven't come across any that are useful, hence the reason I decide to post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some previous question:

There is information on Select with index here:
[selenium-python-select-the-first-item-from-a-drop-down-by-index-is-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413232/selenium-python-select-the-first-item-from-a-drop-down-by-index-is-not-working)

More on select with name etc:
[selenium-python-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382415/selenium-python-select)